# When is it interesting to work with doctrine migrations and when it is not?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, migration, saas

I recently started a new sf2.8 project at work and when i suggested to work with doctrine migrations, the project master asked me to prove it was more interesting than the good old doctrine:schema:update to keep database up-to-date.

Actually he already tried to use doctrine migrations on an other project, it was such a mess it have been chosen to reverse. This older project is in saas mode so working with multiples databases (one per cutomer).

So here is my question : when is it interesting to work with doctrine migrations and when it is not ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very quickly my 2 cents on migrations, hoping it will help you to decide:

PRO

- if you work in team it is very useful to provide db changes through migrations to the rest of the team
- if you work in continuous integration you can automate the deploy of db changes easily, as well as rollbacks
- you can keep track of all the db changes in your [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)
- you can write PHP code inside your migration, and in some cases it's useful

CONS

- if it's a long-time running project you will see your migrations directory growing quickly and [there's not any strategy to archive the migrations](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/182)

IMHO it's always a good choice to work with migrations, even if you're a lone-runner because you have everything you get with the schema:update plus all the PRO I listed above

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope it will help to convince my project master